# Spring Converter for Cookie[] on controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a case where I have multiple cookie values that need to be used to populate a single Java object.  I would like to have my controller signature look like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String displayUserData(Person person) {
  ...
}
```

I have created a Converter for Cookie[] to Person and registered it using the addFormatters method on my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, but I can't seem to get Spring to use it.

I have another Converter that works fine and it set up in the same way.  The only difference between the two is that the working one uses a @PathParameter variable instead of a Cookie[].

I know I could just get access to the Cookie[] and run my conversion manually, but that is less elegant than using a Converter.  Any ideas of how to make this work?

btw this is all set up with Spring 3.1 using annotation configuration (no xml anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-cookievalue

Comment: The issue with this is that I would have to map multiple values to parameters and then manually construct my object with those parameters.  I was hoping Spring would be able to use my Converter so I could keep my method signature clean.